# Facebook Access Token Error when sending Notifications to an Array of IDs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have a list of Facebook IDs stored in an array named `myArray`, I'm trying to write some Javascript that will loop through this array and send a notification to each ID.

This is my latest attempt at it:

```
function sendNotifications(){

var myArray = [624523462, 25624523426, 3245451236, 14352654];

for (var q = 0; q < myArray.length; q++) { 

    FB.api( 
   "/"+myArray[q]+"/notifications",
    "POST",
   {
        "template": "This is a test notification!"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log("notification should be sent.");
      } else {
      console.log(response);
         }
      }
     );             
    }}
```

This is giving me the error message:
`message:"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.`

I'm a little confused by this because the player has already logged into my app at this stage. I've already made several requests for information about the player from the Graph API so I'm not sure why it's asking me for an app access token. Do I need a new access token for every notification posted? Or does it run out after a certain amount of time?

I don't know the correct way to go about including it here. Do I make a call for the token at the start of the function and store it as a variable that I then fill in somewhere? Could someone show me the correct syntax to use to achieve this with my current code?

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are n number of endpoint nodes offered by facebook API. Some require user access token, some require app access token, some require page access token depending on the nature of the node. (You may go through [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) to understand about access tokens thoroughly)

Most of the endpoints are served with the **user access token** which is used by the facebook SDKs (`FB.api()` in your case) by default with each call. Hence, you were able to made those several requests successfully. Fair enough.

The [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications) is one that requires **app access token** instead of user access token. The app access token never expires until the credentials of the app is changed.

1. Getting app access token

   option 1-  use - `{app-id}|{app-secret}` directly which is the app access token only.

   option 2-

   ```
   GET /oauth/access_token?
       client_id={app-id}
       &amp;client_secret={app-secret}
       &amp;grant_type=client_credentials
   ```

   **Important- You must not expose app secret on your client side. It's like a password to your application! So you must make this call on the server side only**
2. Usinig app access token

   It's super easy to use any access token, just add the parameter `access_token` and pass it the required value. eg: `/.../notifications?access_token={app-access-token}`
   Idly, you should make this call on your server not on the client side directly.